# How to retrieve role/status of authenticated user?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am new to Laravel.  I have included an additional field in the user's table named status using the line of code given in the code part below. I am trying to learn how to redirect the user based on their roles.

I understand that to retrieve an authenticated user I can use `$user = Auth::user();`  My question is how I can get the status of the authenticated user to be used in a `redirectTo` function that I plan to write.

```php
// This is how I have added the user status field:
$table->enum('status',['user', 'admin', 'disabled'])->default('user');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LoginController, remove the following line.

```php
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Then add a new method `redirectTo()` to the LoginController. The `redirectTo()` method takes precedence over the `redirectTo` property.

```php
public function redirectTo() {

    $role = auth()->user()->status; 

    // Check user status/role
    switch ($role) {
        case 'admin':
            return '/admin';
        case 'user':
            return '/user';
        default:
            return '/login'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Karl Hill