# Customized redirect login Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I am trying set a rule where if a user is a `Worker` or `Auditor` and logs in, he will be redirected to `/post` otherwise he will be redirected to `/charts`. In my default `LoginController.php`, I tried to do something like this:

```
$redirectAuth = Auth::user()->user_type = 'Worker' || Auth::user()->user_type = 'Auditor'
        ? '/post'
        : '/charts';

protected $redirectTo = $redirectAuth;
```

I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '$redirectAuth' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Am I typing something wrong here? I appreciate any answer thanks.

EDIT:

With the assistance of @Karl Hill, I was able to create my customized login:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    $userType = auth()->user()->user_type;

    return $userType == 'Worker' || $userType == 'Auditor' ? '/charts' : 'brethren';
}
```

but of course, this will also work:

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'Worker':
    case 'Auditor':
        return '/charts';
    default:
        return '/post';
}
```

Whichever your coding preference is.

Comment: That error looks like you are trying to call a function to set a class property.  You can't call functions there.

Comment: And if you do move that code to a better spot - you'll need double == signs for comparisons.  (Single for value assignment).

Comment: I tried doing this `$redirectAuth = Auth::user()->user_type == 'Worker' || Auth::user()->user_type == 'Auditor'` but I'm not sure why I still get the same error, where should I put the expression?

Comment: @JustinF please update your question and put all the LoginController code, that can help us how you have changed the laravel authentication system

Comment: Yes, please include the rest of the code! I might be really hard to understand the problem partially.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442071/how-to-retrieve-role-status-of-authenticated-user/55442782#55442782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LoginController, remove the following line.

```php
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Then add a new method `redirectTo()` to the LoginController. The `redirectTo()` method takes precedence over the `redirectTo` property.

```php
public function redirectTo()
{
    $type = auth()->user()->user_type();

    // Check user type
    switch ($type) {
        case 'Worker':
            return '/post';
        case 'Auditor':
            return '/charts';
        default:
            return '/login';
    }
}
```

Comment: What I did is `$type = auth()->user()->user_type;` and did a short hand of `return $userType == 'Worker' || $userType == 'Auditor' ? '/post' : '/chart';` the `redirectTo()` works as what I want. Yes.